# The new design does not work on IE11

Tags: bug, design, left-navigation

The buttons that are now on the left side do not work on IE11.
They are visible but not clickable.

[image]

Comment: The `z-index` of the `left-sidebar` causes the issue for me. Removing it allows me to click the menu items in `IE11`.

Comment: Temp workaround: open the dev tools with F12. Switch the "document mode" (on the black topbar of the devtools on the right) to IE10.  This makes the topbar look unpretty, but all the links and nav seem to function.

Comment: I agree with @user2342558 - as [microsoft has dropped support of IE 9+](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support) in 2016. So a lot of companies are just not going to focus on making it work and shouldn't have to - it will be up to you to make it work. I say this when I worked at 2 places this year where IE was required for certain operations - still not other companies fault they didn't get the message in 2016.

Comment: @JGreenwell The article you mentioned does say they still supports IE 11 though.

Comment: IE11 is a component of Windows 10, and so will technically be supported by Microsoft for the life of the OS, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Windows%2010

Comment: @g00glen00b Microsoft will drop support for IE11 in two (to five have to find article later) years but the fact that they are dropping support and strongly suggesting moving to Edge by defining IE as legacy software kinda points to the need to move development. Granted I get more annoyed with this cause I have had to bendover backwards and work more hours (repeatedly) to make sure something works on IE too. Some point companies need to say - do we really need to support a dying browser?

Comment: Sadly *some* workplaces are in the dinosaur time and still using Windows 7 which can't go above IE11 / move to Edge. (and to make it further insulting, block non-IE browsers from having external internet access on most sites...)

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 was released on 2013-10-17, in some months it will be 5 years old. In terms of browsers, that's *ancient*. As usual for this type of bug, if it's a relatively simple fix, SO will probably implement it. But it's entirely reasonable for people to suggest you use a different browser, and there is no need at all to call them a child for doing so.

Comment: Related: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: Internet Explorer is officially **supported** according to [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161).

Comment: Not supporting IE11 is like giving progressive enhancement the middle finger.  I could understand IE10, but not everyone has access to Edge.  Besides, [IE11 still has a significant market share](https://netmarketshare.com/).

Comment: I retract my comments and admit they were based frustration coming from working for companies (and coding data visualizations for them) that still insist on using IE 9 or 10. I won't delete them so there is still context for others though. Besides, its good to have a visual reminder to breathe before posting :)

Comment: @zero298 Microsoft has expressly deprecated IE and expressly wants you to _refrain_ from accommodating it because otherwise they'll never be rid of the horrible thing. Companies using IE for legacy applications have no motivation or indeed cost justification for disruptive change when there is any other option. Nothing will move them to action short of pulling the rug out from under them.

Comment: Related: [What is after Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7? How well will ES2016 be supported in enterprises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35184048) | [At what point will IE 10 (and 11) be older than three versions old?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50974143) The common theme in my answers there is 1) IE11 support will continue for the lifetime of the version of Windows it's bundled with 2) as a dev, support IE11 either in enterprises where Edge on Windows 10 is not an option, or if you just feel sorry for Windows 7 users (who for whatever reason insist on using IE and not a different browser).

Comment: @JGreenwell: Microsoft hasn't announced anything regarding IE11. The five years might be referring to the [extended support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet) period Windows usually undergoes after its first five years of mainstream support. This includes Windows 10 LTSB, which doesn't include Edge, which means IE11 will be supported until *at least* 2025. Hopefully everyone will have moved on long before then, of course, since that's still 7 years out.

Comment: @BoltClock missed opportunity to say *that's still 6 to 8 years out* ... disappointing ...